# Is it possible to use single resource file for multiple languages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently using multiple resource files for the different languages in my application.Can I be able to use a single resource file for multiple languages.

Comment: Which are you trying to achieve, a single Resx file with multiple languages in it or a single DLL with multiple languages in it. Also when you say "Automatically translates" do you mean it runs through Google Translate or some other service and automatically gives you the other language? Right now the tile of your question and the body of your question are asking for two different things.

Comment: you are right!!! I am confused. My application supports multi language and i am  using different resource files for different languages .I want to use a single resource file for multiple languages .Any possibilities in that way.

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions. I asked you a "Either/or" question and a "Yes/no" question. You responded with "You are right"... Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32687468/edit) and add more details explaining exactly what you are trying to accomplish..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain please let me know if i could do in that way as i explained above .I am new to this so.

Comment: I don't understand what way you are explaining, that is why I asked you to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32687468/edit) and add more details. Currently your question is unclear as to what you are trying to do so no one can tell you "how to do it" because no one understands what you are trying to do.

Comment: for english we specify example.en.resx and for french we specify example.fr.resx .So can we have a single file that supports both languages.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Am I clear now:(

Comment: @varkhedi - what is clear that your post had almost nothing to do with question you had based on you comments. "How to call web service to translate text" is hard to guess from the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I asked the question just to know how many ways can i achieve that . You are telling its hard to guess ,then what's the point of me  asking a question  that I have to try yet.I think you are an experienced one if its hard for you to guess think of me who is a fresher.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must have a `resx` file per language (`example.en.resx` and `example.fr.resx` for english and french). The only exception to this is the one "default" one that it will use if the resource is not defined in the language specific file (`example.resx` with no language code).

Comment: you mean to say its not possible !!What if my application supports More than 10 languages .Should I have to create 10 different resource files

Comment: Yes, that is correct, your project will have 10 different resource files.

Comment: Wish resource file supported dynamic values for a value field.:(:(

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic values", Remember you can make `Hello, my name is {0}` in `example.en.resx` and `Hola, mi nombre es {0}` in `example.es.resx` then use `String.Format(Resoruces.GreetingString, "Scott")` and it will print the correct language while still using dynamic content.

Comment: By Default the value in resource file will be in english .But once if i choose french the content which  is in english will be translated to french. @Scott Chamberlain

Comment: For that you need to access a Web service like Google Translate, .NET will not just "automatically" do it, you need to find a service that does it for you. Most have limits on the number of translations you can do per day for free, you will likely need to pay for it to have any kind of volume.

Comment: So that is what I was asking.I know it will not translate "automatically".But how can i make use of services through resource files??.

Comment: Write a function`public static string TranslateThis(string source) { /* Call web service here */ }` Every time you go to use a resource run it through the translator `label.Text = TranslateThis(Resource.Greeting);`